# "Cannot run program "cmd"" java maven quote

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am new to Java and Maven and Netbeans and I've been trying to make it work for a couple of days now. I have no idea what is wrong with it. I've tried reinstalling java and maven but it doesn't work. And the full error message that I get is 
"cd C:\Users\HOME\Documents\NetBeansProjects\g056\trunk\wk01\fraction; "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241" cmd /c "\"\"C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\netbeans\java\maven\bin\mvn.cmd\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\netbeans\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 test\""
Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "C:\Users\HOME\Documents\NetBeansProjects\g056\trunk\wk01\fraction"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: "C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\netbeans\java\maven\bin\mvn.cmd" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Users\HOME\Desktop\netbeans\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 test
"

Comment: Can you please add more details about what is not working, building the project, deploying the project or what is it? Also can you please let us know what have you tried?

Comment: Hello. To get better help please [edit] your question and provide more details about what you want to achieve, what ware your attempt and what happened instead, preferably as [mcve].

Comment: What were you trying to do? running a program from the command line? or doing mvn clean install?

Comment: I tried running j unit tests, everything with maven and java seems fine to me. I've reinstalled java, maven, and Netbeans.